# Регулярное выражение для поиска поиска повторяющихся символов в слове

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

Регулярное выражение должно отсеивать слова, в которых буквы из определенного класса символов повторяются более одного раза.
Ну например наши символы [abc]

```
abc +

aabc -

abac -

abczsa -

cba +
```

Получается только отсеять слова, если повторяющиеся буквы стоят рядом (`aabc`). Длина слова произвольная. Количество повторений букв произвольно.

Comment: Покажите код того, что у вас уже получилось сделать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Первое что приходит в голову - пойти от обратного. Найти те слова где символы повторяются, а потом через `!regExp.test(str)` найти нужные значения:

```js
const strings = [ 'abc', 'aabc', 'abac', 'abczsa', 'cba', 'ggkk' ],
  regExp = /([abc])\w*\1/i;

for(let str of strings) {
  console.log(`${str}: ${!regExp.test(str)}`);
}
```

Comment: `ggkk // false`, что не соответствует задаче

Comment: @ReinRaus, какому условию это не соответствует?

Comment: Первый абзац вопроса.

Comment: @ReinRaus, а, "класса", да, невнимательно прочел, поправил

Comment: @MedvedevDev не совсем понятно что здесь подразумевается под `\\w` и `\\1`. В моем понимании это экранирование символа 'слеша'. Можно это каким-либо образом заменить эквивалентной конструкцией?

Comment: @Мараша, условности языка (так как передается не регексп, а строка содержащая регексп). Поменял на более привычный вариант.